# how to handle the exception in oracle fusion web service em3 for standard Receipt

Tags: java, soap, fusion

I am using the oracle fusion SOAP web service

```
QName: {http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/receivables
/receipts/shared/standardReceiptService/commonService/}StandardReceiptService
```

i am using em3 i.e. em3.oraclecloud.com
My code is working fine if the receipt is created successfully. I wanted to know how can i get the response from fusion if i get some error? or How can i get the fault payload or something like that.

```
try{
    ObjectFactory obj = new ObjectFactory();
    StandardReceipt standardReceipt = new StandardReceipt();
    AmountType amt = new AmountType();
    amt.setCurrencyCode("USD");
    amt.setValue(new BigDecimal(100));
    standardReceipt.setAmount(amt);
    standardReceipt.setCurrencyCode("USD");
    standardReceipt.setOrgId(new Long(102));
    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(new java.util.Date());
    XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
    standardReceipt.setReceiptDate(date2);
    standardReceipt.setReceiptMethodId(new Long(102));
    standardReceipt.setReceiptNumber(obj.createStandardReceiptReceiptNumber(123));
    c.setTime(new Date());
    date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
    standardReceipt.setIssueDate(obj.createStandardReceiptIssueDate(date2));
    c.setTime(new Date());
    date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
    standardReceipt.setAnticipatedClearingDate(obj.createStandardReceiptAnticipatedClearingDate(date2));
    standardReceipt.setCustomerSiteUseId(obj.createStandardReceiptCustomerSiteUseId(new Long(103)));
    standardReceipt.setCustomerId(obj.createStandardReceiptCustomerId((new Long(1039))));
    StandardReceiptResult result =standardReceiptPort.createStandardReceipt(standardReceipt);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i can see in the logs using Soap Handler. But will it me in recognizing the error front side as well?